# on mouse move how to change the particular segment in helix toolkit in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, mesh, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to highlight particular segment of mesh .

I am having a 3D model mesh in helix toolkit .What I am trying to do is , on mouse move I found  the particular segment of mesh and I want to differentiate it without re-drawing this on my mesh .
I don't want to overlay this segment on my Mesh .
The re-drawing makes my software slow. So ,what I need is, how could I highlight this particular segment in mesh without redrawing them . I am using Helix toolkit in C#

Comment: First of all, how large meshes are we talking about? WPF should handle fairly large models in real time even with integrated graphics. So a good first step is to ensure you are not doing anything else that tanks performance. Compare with something like windows 3D viewer to get a sense of the performance you should get.

Comment: Second, what do you mean by "segment". A mesh is typically the smallest unit that is drawn. You might be able redraw only a single mesh, but it will likely be complicated, involving multiple pixels buffers that needs to be composited, and a high level framework like WPF might not give the needed control. A somewhat common practice is to use lower detailed meshes as placeholders to speed up rendering, i.e. "Level of Detail".

Comment: OK, I am having a point cloud data that contains points (x,y,z) . So the total points is 6,58,000 points. These points are added to Meshgeometry3D and Meshes are created to these points. . A set  of 1600 (x,y,z) points are called as segment .By dividing 6,58,000/1600 we get 411 parts (i.e) segments .Moving mouse over this particular segment  , I retrieved those points. But I can't highlight this particular segment. I think , this time I explained correctly..